# In Angular, what are the advantages of using Renderer over ElementRef?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I'm new in Angular and I was trying to create my own directive using two options:

- Option 1: Direct access to the elements using ElementRef
- Option 2: Using the Renderer2

Option 1:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appBasicHighlight]'
})
export class BasicHighlightDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBetterHighlight]'
})
export class BetterHighlightDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'blue');
  }
}
```

The instructor from the tutorial said that it is much safer and recommended to use the Renderer over the direct access but didn't explain explicitly the reasons. He meant direct DOM access by using ElementRef but as you can see from the code, Renderer used ElementRef too. With this, I'm confused on what makes Renderer safer and advantageous over ElementRef.

Answer (score 6):

From angular document

> "Permitting direct access to the DOM can make your application more
>   vulnerable to XSS attacks. Carefully review any use of ElementRef in
>   your code. For more detail, see the Security Guide."
>
> "Use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed.
>   Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular instead.
>   Alternatively you take a look at Renderer which provides API that can
>   safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not
>   supported."

Or another explain when we need to use renderer

> The Renderer is a class that is a partial abstraction over the DOM.
>   Using the Renderer for manipulating the DOM doesn't break server-side
>   rendering or Web Workers (where direct access to the DOM would break).
>
> The Renderer2 class is an abstraction provided by Angular in the form
>   of a service that allows to manipulate elements of your app without
>   having to touch the DOM directly. This is the recommended approach
>   because it then makes it easier to develop apps that can be rendered
>   in environments that don’t have DOM access, like on the server, in a
>   web worker or on native mobile.

So when direct access to native elements is not supported you should use renderer

Comment: Thanks for that but looking for why Renderer "can safely be used".

Answer (score 0):

The author of this tutorial explains why it's a better approach. He says 'because it could be that your application is not running in an environment where it has access to the DOM. Angular also works with ServiceWorkers...'. It's in Angular The Complete Guide (2021 Edition), lesson 94, 5:40

and see:
https://betterprogramming.pub/angular-manipulate-properly-the-dom-with-renderer-16a756508cba